# Xuggler-Java- How to create packets from a byte array?

Tags: java, h.264, video-encoding, avi, xuggle

I am building an export application using Xuggler that exports a h264 encoded recording so that it can be played in an external player ( writing the video recording to .avi or .mp4 container).

I am interested to know how one could create a IPacket from a byte array representing a video frame. What parameters from the IPacket need to be set and what values should those contain?
And again what parameters should be set and what should be their values for the container that gathers the packets?

Comment: Why not read the video with a IContainer instead and it will set up the packets for you automatically? See http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IContainer.html

Comment: I am obliged to use the frames that are represented by byte arrays. I am not sure how to set the timestamp, pts and dts and how these affect the length of the video recording.

Comment: packet = IPacket.make( IBuffer.make( null, data, 0, data.length )); and set the apropriate time stamp for the packet:  packet.setTimeStamp( time );  and packet.setTimeBase( IRational.make(1,1000) ); int pksz = packet.getSize(); packet.setComplete(true, pksz);

Answer (score 4):

```
packet = IPacket.make( IBuffer.make( null, data, 0, data.length ));
packet.setTimeStamp( time );
packet.setTimeBase( IRational.make(1,1000) ); 
int pksz = packet.getSize(); 
packet.setComplete(true, pksz);
```